# Vite imports all .env fields for firebase config file except projectId

Tags: javascript, firebase, config, vite

I've placed all my variables for the firebase config file into a separate env file. Everything is retrieving correctly EXCEPT projectId.

Everything will only work if I paste the projectId string in there directly. If I have it as import.meta.env.VITE_PROJECT_ID it refuses to work and gives me:

@firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.7.2): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Permission denied on resource project {{projectname}},.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.

If I replace import.meta.env.VITE_PROJECT_ID with the actual projectId string, but leave everything else as import.meta.env.{variable}.... everything works.

Can anyone help?

```js
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: import.meta.env.VITE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: import.meta.env.VITE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: import.meta.env.VITE_MESSAGE_SENDER_ID,
  appId: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_ID,
};

console.log("this is the", firebaseConfig.projectId)


// Initialize Firebase
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const db = getFirestore(app);
```

Comment: Have you tried logging the value of `import.meta.env.VITE_PROJECT_ID` to see if it contains the value you expect?

Comment: Yes console.log("this is the", import.meta.env.VITE_PROJECT_ID) gives exactly the string I want in there. This exact string works if I paste it in there directly but not when it is import.meta.env.  @DougStevenson